# PHP function in array

Tags: php

My problem is that retrieveName() is not getting $1's value, but $1 is working just fine in the previous instance.

```
    function bbcode ($string)
    {
    // All the default bbcode arrays.
    $bbcode = array(
    '#\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/quote\]#si' => 
'<span class="bbcode_quote"><b>
<a href="userprofile.php?id='.stripslashes('$1').'" target="_blank">
<span class="fake_link">'.retrieveName('$1').'</span></a> Said:</b><BR/>$2</span><BR/>'

    );
    $output = preg_replace(array_keys($bbcode), array_values($bbcode), $string);
    $output = str_replace("\\r\\n", "<br>", $output);
    return $output;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
there's no strip slashes, I wish it was that simple

```
function retrieveName($poster_id){
$get_name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = 'sanitizeIn($poster_id)'")
or die(mysql_error());
$name_row = mysql_fetch_array($get_name);
return $name_row['username'];
}
function sanitizeIn ($string) {
$output = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
return $output;
}
```

Comment: Might have to double-escape it, into "\\\\1", depending on how many levels of processing are done within retrieveName()

Comment: Do all the variables that are passed to retrieveName begin with \\? If they do, why not just pass the integer value (1) and then append '\\' inside the retrieveName function?

Comment: look inside  `retrieveName` use might be using `stripslashes`

Comment: The code is supposed to be sending \\1's value to the function, not \\1 itself. my problem is that I'm unsure how to quote it properly, because of that it's taking \\1 as a string rather than a variable sent from the first part of the array

Comment: Are you using `preg_replace_callback` ? Show all of the relative code.

Comment: @xdazz I added all of the relative code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `preg_*` functions, as you should be, you should use `$1` instead of `\\1`. Both are valid, but `$1` is the preferred syntax.

Also, you might be more interested in one of the following:

```
$output = preg_replace("#\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/quote\]#sie",  
  "'<span class=\"bbcode_quote\"><b><a href=\"userprofile.php?id='.stripslashes('$1').'\"
    target=\"_blank\"><span class=\"fake_link\">'. 
   retrieveName(stripslashes('$1')) . '</span></a> Said:</b><BR/>$2 
  </span><BR/>'",$input);
```

Or:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback("#\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/quote\]#si",function($m) {
    return '<span class="bbcode_quote"><b><a href="userprofile.php?id=\\1"  
    target="_blank"><span class="fake_link">' .  
   retrieveName('\\1') . '</span></a> Said:</b><BR/>\\2 
  </span><BR/>';
},$input);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I made some changes in my first post accordingly. But $1 is still not passing the value to retrieveName();

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback("#\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/quote\]#si",function($matches) {
    return '<span class="bbcode_quote"><b><a href="userprofile.php?id='.stripslashes($matches[1]).'" target="_blank"><span class="fake_link">' .  
    retrieveName($matches[1]).'</span></a> Said:</b><BR/>'.$matches[2].'</span><BR/>';
},$input);
```